# finding range by comparing two tables

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table in database as "EXPERIENCE RANGE" with rows as (I can also edit this table according to my need)

```
0
0.5
1
2
3
5
10
20
```

I have total experience as integer. I need to display the range in which it lies.

Example -  for experience of 8, Range will be 5 - 10

I need to write a sql query. Any ideas will be quite helpful as I am new to SQL.

I cannot hard code it..need to take values from tables only.

Comment: I assume this is Oracle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you are using Oracle, the following query works fine with your existing table:

```
SELECT
  ( SELECT MAX( value ) FROM experience_range WHERE value <= :search_value ) AS range_start,
  ( SELECT MIN( value ) FROM experience_range WHERE value >  :search_value ) AS range_end
FROM dual;
```

No need to hardcode the values, and no need to store the lower and upper bounds redundantly.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it with [CASE](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/expressions004.htm) Expression, the syntax is:

```
SELECT
CASE 
    WHEN experience >= 0 and experience <= 4 THEN '0-4'
    WHEN experience >= 5 and experience <= 10 THEN '5-10'
    .....
    ELSE 'No Range'
END as Range
FROM Table_Name
```

Comment: I cannot hardcode. Need to take input from table only.

Comment: means if someone changes the value in the table, the range should change accordingly and I don't have to change the code

Answer (score 0):

If you do need to store the ranges in a table, I would personally suggest altering the structure of the range table (Assuming you are able to), maybe something like:

```
|--------------------------------------|
|ID|DESCRIPTION|LOWER_LIMIT|UPPER_LIMIT|
|1 |  0 - 0.5  |     0     |     0.5   |
|2 |  0.5 - 1  |    0.5    |      1    |
                    ...
```

Then you could get your range by running something like:

```
SELECT DESCRIPTION FROM [RANGES] WHERE <VALUE> >= LOWER_LIMIT AND <VALUE> < UPPER_LIMIT
```

EDIT - Mikhail's answer also works, defining the ranges within the query itself is also an option and probably simpler providing you don't need to get these ranges from several reports. (That would require editing every report/query individually)

EDIT 2 - I see you are not able to hardcode the ranges, in which case the above would be best. Can I ask why you are unable to hardcode them?

Comment: project requirement prohibits use of hardcoding coz these range will be used in lots of different places and it will be difficult to change the ranges in future in every places